# С помощью method.invoke не получается вызвать функцию из другого модуля

Tags: c#, исключения, методы

Пытаюсь вызвать метод из другого модуля по названию метода в переменной  verb. Однако, на моменте, где я использую method.invoke, происходит исключение!

```
string verb = lib_this_command[1]; //lib_this_command[1] = hello
SysLib runVerb = new SysLib();
MethodInfo method = runVerb.GetType().GetMethod(verb);
method.Invoke(runVerb, null);
```

Причем, если вместо массива lib_this_command[1] использовать простую строку "hello", то исключений не возникает!

Код модуля SysLib:

```
using System;

namespace F__
{
    class SysLib
    {
        public void hello()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Поправил код в ответе.

Comment: В вопросе неправильно оформил код, извиняюсь. Воспользовался этим кодом: ````               string verb = lib_this_command[1];
SysLib instance = new SysLib();
MethodInfo method = instance.GetType().GetMethod(verb);
method.Invoke(instance, null);```` lib_this_command[1] равен "hello". Однако, происходит исключение: System.NullReferenceException: Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта. Причем, если на месте массива указать просто строку "hello", то код заработает.

Comment: Не надо писать код в комментариях, его там невозможно читать.

Comment: _если вместо массива lib_this_command[1] использовать простую строку "hello", то исключений не возникает!_ - так посмотрите в отладичке, что содержит `lib_this_command[1]`, оно содержит явно не `hello`, а что-то другое, пробел там лишний или еще что-нибудь, чего явно не видно.

Comment: lib_this_command[1] равен именно hello. Без пробелов, без всего. Итог такой: System.NullReferenceException: Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.

Comment: @Feen нет, `lib_this_command[1]` **НЕ** равен `"hello"`, иначе бы при замене `lib_this_command[1]` на `"hello"` ничего бы не изменилось

Comment: покажите код инициализации или, хотя бы, скрин, на котором вы просматриваете значение `lib_this_command[1]`